# how to update iphone Simulator and Device to 3.1?

Tags: iphone, version, device

I have Xcode version 3.1.3 and in that Simulator and Device is supported till 3.0.
I want to update the Simulator and Device for 3.1.After that i will be able to put my data from Xcode to My Real Device OS 3.1.

how to update from 3.0 to 3.1 in Xcode in Mac mini?

If any body has any resolution or any other way ,which would appreciated.

Thanks,

Mishal Shah

Comment: at this point, Xcode is at version 3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your version of the developer tools from Apple's [iPhone developer website](http://developer.apple.com/iphone).